# Use run a particular code first

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio, configuration

My project structure is similar to this link
https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+c%23+visual+studio+structure&biw=1920&bih=951&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigscz4h63NAhUkMJoKHXGbD5IQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=PcdTohsKspnG9M%3A

Comment: Show the angular promise code

Comment: edited in the question now

Comment: I didn't ask where you took help from. Show the code you wrote.

Comment: that is the same code i use. i want the ajax call to be called first. but thats not happening. i want to know if i can put this ajax call somewhere in the config and make sure if the config file runs first and then other page controllers.

Comment: No it doesn't work like that. You call and then wait for the response rather than moving forward. I am still confused about your existing code, why don't you copy and paste it in this question ?

Comment: done. pls have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **config block** is suited well for two pieces of code that might help you.

Firstly, you can use it to inject an $http interceptor that will handle failed authentication calls and redirect.

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
    });
```

You can write this **$http intercepter** as a factory called 'authInterceptor' (not shown). More [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-angularjs-interceptors-with-http), but the main point is it can look for certain status codes from $http responses, such as 401, and redirect to your error page as needed

Depending on **your routing you are using**, you can use the routes **resolve** property to hold on loading the route until the data is resolved. If it is rejected, *the intercepter you created will reroute*.

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $http) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller:'MainCtrl',
                template:'<h1>Hello!<h1>',
                resolve:{
                    userData: return $http.get('/api/authentication');
                }
            });
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
    });
```

One final alternative would be to you the **run block** instead to make the initial authentication call. The run block runs after the config but before your app loads.

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $http) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
    })
    .run(function ($http) {
        $http.get('/api/authentication');
    });
```

I wouldn't try and just run this code. You have to write the intercepter service. You have to have a router module loaded, etc. Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you `$.ajax` with `$http` of angular and wait for the promise call:

```
var checkUserlogin = function() {
    return $http.get(serviceURL_CheckUserExists)
           .then(function (response) {
                if (response.Results.length == 1 && response.Results[0].BlockUser == false) {
                    return response.Results[0].User_ID.trim();
                } else {
                    return null; // could not login
                }
           });
};
```

**PS:** I have not tested this code, if you get any error do let me know.

Comment: Shaharyar- tried this bit of code and it still shows a loading page

Comment: What does it do in emitted the event `getUserName`? and why are you calling `loadData` with out any condition?

Comment: it is just emiting the result to other controllers... so they can grab it and use it